# Why there is no forum like DSP educators or tag like teaching?

Tags: discussion

There is http://www.matheducators.stackexchange.com/ 
  which is a question and answer site for those involved in the field of teaching mathematics.

Also, there is a tag https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching 
which tells that Mathematics education consists in the practice of teaching and learning mathematics, along with the associated research. Research in mathematics education concerns the tools, methods and approaches that facilitate the practice of mathematics or the study of this practice.

So my question is why there is  no tag like "teaching" in the http://www.dsp.stackexchange.com  or no forum  like DSP educators ?  I request you those have high reputation to please take steps and start it.

Answer (score 1):

Good point! Feel free to see if there are any existing questions that should have a `teaching` tag and edit them to add the tag. Or let us know here which questions you'd suggest to allow the tag to be created.

Comment: K sir, this is the question.   http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/how-the-topic-of-frequency-domain-be-taught  But I didn't find suitable tag  on dsp .stack exchange site

Comment: That's what I'm asking you to do: find a question that you think merits it (or make one yourself) add the tag and I can approve.  If you can't add the new tag, let me know (by posting here) which question should be tagged and I'll tag it.

Comment: OK, that's done! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much  :-) and sorry for disturbance given by me.

Comment: No problem at all! You see to want to help out the site, which is all good.